# Exception handling in scala

Tags: scala, exception, either

I am working on an application with Scala. I am trying to implement Exception Handling in the application. I tried using `Either` for handling the exceptions. For simple cases, it seems to be enough to handle exceptions. However, when I need to get results from multiple tables by joins, the exception handling is creating more issues than solving. My application structure is explained below:

Using repository pattern for the database operations which defines all the database interaction operations. For eg, I have a central repository which defines `findAll`, `findById`, `insert`, `delete`, `update`, `exists` etc. My `findAll` methods signature has been changed to `Either[CustomException, List[TEntity]]`, similarly `findById` methods type is `Either[CustomException, Option[TEntity]]`.

Now assume that, If I need to fetch employees from database in my method, i will be doing something like below :

```
def getVehicleById(id:Long) = {

val vehicle = repository.findById(id)
//i have one-to-one mapping with Employee table for the driver of the vehicle
val driver = empRepository.findById(vehicle.driverId)

}
```

Now the type of vehicle will be `Either[CustomException, Option[Vehicle]]` and type of driver is `Either[CustomException, Employee]`

If i need to do any more operation after getting the results, i have to use case Right/Left and then do that. The problem is that, may be inside the Right case, I might need to join with another table, which makes the result of that as again `Either[CustomException, Entity]`. if any error occurs in that operation, i need to again use try catch block. 
I feel that this kind of hanling becomes very difficult to manage when the code complexity increases, and also I will have a lot of boiler plate code to handle these situations, which goes against Scala principle itself.

So my question is, how can I handle exception in a better way without much boiler plate code.

Note : I am coming from a Java background, have been working on Scala only for a couple of months now.

**EDIT**

Adding Sample Code with Try :
This sample is very close to the requirement I have.

```
import scala.util._
def checkTry:Try[List[Int]] = Success(List(2))
def checkTryStr:Try[String] = Success("Asd")

def getVehicleWithDriver = for {
  a <- checkTry
  c <- a
  b <- checkTryStr
}yield {
  (c,b)
}
getVehicleWithDriver
```

But with the bove code, I am getting compilation errors.

> ```
> Error:(9, 6) type mismatch;
>  found   : scala.util.Try[(Int, String)]
>  required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
>   b <- checkTryStr
>     ^
> Error:(9, 6) type mismatch;
>  found   : scala.util.Try[(Int, String)]
>  required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
>   b <- checkTryStr
>     ^
> Error:(8, 6) type mismatch;
>  found   : List[Nothing]
>  required: scala.util.Try[?]
>   c <- a
>     ^
> ```

Comment: I don't see the name of `Try` in your question, so you may want to know of it: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. But isn't the same with try as well. Instead of matching with right/left, i ll have to match with Try and wouldnt that also create a very huge nested try statements ?

Comment: How about scalaz' alternative methods? http://typelevel.org/blog/2014/02/21/error-handling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `for`/`yield` sugar. You can either get in the habit of putting `.right` on all your `Either`s, or as @Gangstead suggests, use `\/` from Scalaz. (There are certainly scary parts of Scalaz - I've been using it for 4 years and am still intimidated by e.g. `Strength` - but it's perfectly possible to start with the easy parts and work your way up).

```
for {
  vehicle <- repository.findById(id).right
  driver <- empRepository.findById(vehicle.driverId).right
  somethingElse <- somePossiblyFailingComputation.right
} yield somethingElse
//Don't need the .right if you're using Scalaz \/
```

Other vital hints: when you want to apply an effectful function to a List, you want to use Scalaz `traverse`:

```
vehicleList <- vehicleIdList.traverse(repository.findById) //assuming you're using \/
//might need a few .right if you're using Either
```

When you're calling Java code that might throw an exception, use `scala.util.control.Exception`'s `catching`:

```
val myEither = catching(classOf[SomeException]) either someJavaMethodThatThrows()
// (...).disjunction if you're using \/.
```

If you need to work with another kind of "effectful context" at the same time as working with `Either`/`\/`, you'll have to start looking at *monad transformers*, but it might be best to get comfortable with just `Either` first.

Hope that helps; best of luck, hope you like Scala.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But my worry is that, I have to put .right everywhere when I use Either. And what if it is actually Left and not right that is there in the Either. I have to put the case Right/Left everywhere. right?

Comment: No, `.right` will handle a `Left` or `Right` correctly, it's just syntax to make mapping work correctly. If you don't want to have to put the `.right` everywhere (and I agree with that), use Scalaz's `\/` instead, and you can use `for`/`yield` without any `.right`s.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Scalaz's disjunction `\/`.

A warning: Scalaz is hardcore scala written by hardcore guys.

Take a look at Brendon McAdams' (@Rit) presentation about ["Scalaz' Gateway Drugs"](https://speakerdeck.com/bwmcadams/scala-exchange-2014-a-skeptics-look-at-scalaz-gateway-drugs-a-practical-exploration).  He's much more approachable for programmers coming from Java, and he keeps it very practicall

Comment: Yeah. I tried understanding Scalaz, but it was going way above my head.. :(

Comment: I only considered using it after seeing Brendon's presentation.  He's got sample code and makes disjunction look really useful.  His example is your use case: replacing Eithers to handle db lookup failures easier.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Try`, not `Either`. It is a monad, so you can `map` or `flatMap` it, or use it in a `for` comprehension. It looks pretty elegant actually.

```
def getVehicleWithDriver(id: String): Try [(Vehicle, Driver)] = for {
    vehicle <- repository. findById(id)
    driver <- empRepository.findById(vehicle.driverId)
} yield {
    (vehicle, driver)
}
```

Comment: The problem with `Try` is that you lose type safety - the failure could be any `Throwable`. Better to use scalaz `\/`.

Comment: I am not sure I see the value of type safety for failures. You can use `case e: SpecificException` when handling specific types of failures, and let the unmatched ones propagate up to the caller. This is a standard way of handling exceptions.

Comment: The value of type safety for failures is the same as the value of type safety for any other value.

Comment: Even if I use Try, i still need to do a lot of nesting of Success/Failure for handing complex queries/method calls. If I build the queries directly,I am somehow able to reduce the code. The issue come when I need to use the repository pattern. All the methods signature will be Try[Something]/ Try[List[Something]] etc. If I call different methods in the repository in a single method for different processing,I need to write a lot of Case stmt. Thats the main worry. I am wondering if the problem s due to my lack of complete understanding of scala or that is the only way to handle such situations.

Comment: @YaduKrishnan yes, the signatures will be Try[Something], that is comparable to Java's `Something throws Exception`.  You should not need "a lot of case statements" though. A single `for` comprehension should suffice for most of your needs. See the sample function in my answer.

Comment: @Dima : I edited the question with sample Try code. But getting compilation errors. That is one of the type of data that I have very often.

Comment: Yeah, you can't mix Try's and lists in the same for comprehension. 
For the case of your example, you'd need to do something like `for { a <- checkTry; b <- checkTryStr } yield a.map { (_, b) }`